# How to give limited access to client user in Window Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

How can I control on my client Pc's. 
For example: I want that user cannot access internet, or user will unable to access control panel, my computer properties and other stuff like this.
I hope you understand; what I am asking.

Help will be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: This is all fairly standard stuff for a server environment. Have you done any research on how to achieve these tasks?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution to this.

Create your users in your AD, create groups and then add **GPO** to these groups.
GPO stands for **Group Policy Object**, in which you can define many things.

One of those things is not being able to open configuration panel. 
*You can start the Group Policy Management Console with gpmc.msc or by going to All Programs > Administrative Tools > Group Policy Management.*

EDIT: This might come in handy for you [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147307(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147307%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)